# AJAX error when using a custom ViewsFilter?

Tags: 8, ajax, views

I have created a custom field that is a collection of a couple things, one being a taxonomy entity reference.  Now I want to be able to filter a view based on this taxonomy reference.  With the code below I see the correct entity reference and can find the correct terms and everything looks good until I click save.

Then it throws this giant AJAX error that i cannot make heads or tails of.

ajax.js?v=8.1.3:965 Uncaught AjaxError:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /admin/structure/views/view/category_news_block_6/preview/music
StatusText: OK
ResponseText: 'Technology (25)''Technology (25)'[{"command":"settings","settings":{"ajaxPageState":{"theme":"onsetadmin","libraries":"abheading\/abheading,archived_favorites\/ajax_saving,classy\/base,classy\/messages,classy\/node,contextual\/drupal.contextual-links,contextual\/drupal.contextual-links,contextual\/drupal.contextual-toolbar,core\/drupal.active-link,core\/drupal.autocomplete,core\/drupal.collapse,core\/drupal.collapse,core\/drupal.dialog.ajax,core\/drupal.dialog.ajax,core\/drupal.states,core\/drupal.tabledrag,core\/drupal.tableresponsive,core\/html5shiv,core\/jquery.ui.tabs,core\/normalize,event_calendar\/event_calendar_lib,find\/find_lib,ga_report\/ga_send,import\/ncs,login_mod\/logout,my_podcast\/podcast-js,ncsdev\/ipad_fixes,onsetadmin\/bootstrap,onsetadmin\/global-styling,poll\/drupal.poll-links,scroll_menu\/scroll,seven\/global-styling,shortcut\/drupal.shortcut,social_media\/social_media_style,socialmedianode\/socialmedianode_style,toolbar\/toolbar,toolbar\/toolbar.escapeAdmin,tour\/tour,urltracking\/urltracking_form_style,user\/drupal.user.icons,video\/video_form,views\/views.module,views_ui\/views_ui.admin","theme_token":"gEoIQ537BMQtSpWSiqEYebhCssHSDCwaCPLN1224XqM"},"ajaxTrustedUrl":{"\/admin\/structure\/views\/view\/category_news_block_6\/preview\/music":true},"ajax":{"preview-submit":{"url":"\/admin\/structure\/views\/view\/category_news_block_6\/preview\/music","wrapper":"views-preview-wrapper","event":"click","progress":{"type":"fullscreen"},"method":"replaceWith","disable-refocus":true,"dialogType":"ajax","submit":{"_triggering_element_name":"op","_triggering_element_value":"Update preview"}}},"pluralDelimiter":"\u0003","user":{"uid":"1","permissionsHash":"fd4956e871fce9817761b65924d9442c46e3c597742b03fc3169b17173425acb"}},"merge":true},{"command":"insert","method":null,"selector":null,"data":"\u003Cdiv id=\u0022views-preview-wrapper\u0022 class=\u0022views-preview-wrapper views-admin clearfix\u0022\u003E\u003Cform class=\u0022view-preview-form view-form\u0022 data-drupal-selector=\u0022views-ui-preview-form\u0022 action=\u0022\/admin\/structure\/views\/view\/category_news_block_6\/preview\/music\u0022 method=\u0022post\u0022 id=\u0022views-ui-preview-form\u0022 accept-charset=\u0022UTF-8\u0022\u003E\n  \u003Ch2 class=\u0022view-preview-form__title\u0022\u003EPreview\u003C\/h2\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022js-form-item form-item js-form-type-checkbox form-type-checkbox js-form-item-live-preview form-item-live-preview\u0022\u003E\n        \u003Cinput data-drupal-selector=\u0022edit-displays-live-preview\u0022 type=\u0022checkbox\u0022 id=\u0022edit-displays-live-preview\u0022 name=\u0022live_preview\u0022 value=\u00221\u0022 checked=\u0022checked\u0022 class=\u0022form-checkbox\u0022 \/\u003E\n\n        \u003Clabel for=\u0022edit-displays-live-preview\u0022 class=\u0022option\u0022\u003EAuto preview\u003C\/label\u003E\n      \u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022js-form-item form-item js-form-type-textfield form-type-textfield js-form-item-view-args form-item-view-args\u0022\u003E\n      \u003Clabel for=\u0022preview-args\u0022\u003EPreview with contextual filters:\u003C\/label\u003E\n        \u003Csection id=\u0022auth-button\u0022\u003E\u003C\/section\u003E\n\u003Csection id=\u0022view-selector-1\u0022\u003E\u003C\/section\u003E\n\n\n\u003Cinput data-drupal-selector=\u0022preview-args\u0022 aria-describedby=\u0022preview-args--description\u0022 type=\u0022text\u0022 id=\u0022preview-args\u0022 name=\u0022view_args\u0022 value=\u0022\u0022 size=\u002260\u0022 maxlength=\u0022128\u0022 class=\u0022form-text\u0022 \/\u003E\n\n\n            \u003Cdiv id=\u0022preview-args--description\u0022 class=\u0022description\u0022\u003E\n      Separate contextual filter values with a \u0022\/\u0022. For example, \u003Cem class=\u0022placeholder\u0022\u003E40\/12\/10\u003C\/em\u003E.\n    \u003C\/div\u003E\n  \u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cinput data-drupal-selector=\u0022form-gdz-2l46lu60yf2rt2cblxxvbeck-cnw41cgteidqo\u0022 type=\u0022hidden\u0022 name=\u0022form_build_id\u0022 value=\u0022form--GDZ_2l46LU60Yf2rT2CblxXvbeCk_cNw41cgtEIdqo\u0022 \/\u003E\n\u003Cinput data-drupal-selector=\u0022edit-view-preview-form-form-token-wquwcx8kkz4\u0022 type=\u0022hidden\u0022 name=\u0022form_token\u0022 value=\u0022nOZgTdYSYFgrtq57O-sekR4qqFbs4c02928-_rVCKrE\u0022 \/\u003E\n\u003Cinput data-drupal-selector=\u0022edit-view-preview-form-rudggtaedzm\u0022 type=\u0022hidden\u0022 name=\u0022form_id\u0022 value=\u0022view_preview_form\u0022 \/\u003E\n\u003Cdiv id=\u0022preview-submit-wrapper\u0022 class=\u0022preview-submit-wrapper form-actions js-form-wrapper form-wrapper\u0022 data-drupal-selector=\u0022edit-actions\u0022\u003E\u003Cinput class=\u0022arguments-preview button js-form-submit form-submit\u0022 data-drupal-selector=\u0022preview-submit\u0022 data-disable-refocus=\u0022true\u0022 type=\u0022submit\u0022 id=\u0022preview-submit\u0022 name=\u0022op\u0022 value=\u0022Update preview\u0022 \/\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv id=\u0022views-live-preview\u0022 class=\u0022views-live-preview js-form-wrapper form-wrapper\u0022 data-drupal-selector=\u0022edit-preview\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-query-info\u0022\u003E\u003Ctable data-drupal-selector=\u0022edit-table\u0022 id=\u0022edit-table--AKkl1_P_Zwc\u0022 data-striping=\u00221\u0022\u003E\n  \n  \n  \n    \u003C\/table\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003EUnable to preview due to validation errors.\u003C\/div\u003E\n\n\u003C\/form\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E","settings":null},{"command":"insert","method":"prepend","selector":null,"data":"\n    \u003Cdiv role=\u0022contentinfo\u0022 aria-label=\u0022Error message\u0022 class=\u0022messages messages--error\u0022\u003E\n          \u003Cdiv role=\u0022alert\u0022\u003E\n                  \u003Ch2 class=\u0022visually-hidden\u0022\u003EError message\u003C\/h2\u003E\n                    The value  is not an array for in on filter: : Category\n                \u003C\/div\u003E\n      \u003C\/div\u003E\n    \n","settings":null}]Drupal.Ajax.error @ ajax.js?v=8.1.3:965complete @ ajax.js?v=8.1.3:510t.complete @ jquery.form.min.js?v=3.51:11j @ jquery.js:3099fireWith @ jquery.js:3211x @ jquery.js:8279(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:8605
```

Here is the code i am using for my filter.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_custom_field\Plugin\views\filter;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\filter\InOperator;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Element\EntityAutocomplete;
use Drupal\views\Views;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase;
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;

/**
 * Filter handler for usernames.
 *
 * @ingroup views_filter_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsFilter("custom_field_category")
 */
class CustomCategoryFilter extends InOperator {


  protected function valueForm(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['value'] = array(
        '#title' => $this->t('Category'),
        '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
        '#selection_handler' => 'default:taxonomy_term',
        '#target_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
        '#selection_settings'=> [
            'target_bundle'=> array(
                'category',
            ),
        ],
    );
  }

}
```

and my hook

```
<?php

/**
 * implements hook_views_data_alter
 */
function priority_widget_views_data_alter(array &$data){
  $data['node__field_content_category']['priority_widget_category_filter'] = [
      'title' => t('Category'),
      'filter' => array(
          'title' => t('Category'),
          'help' => 'Searches the category field in the Priority Widget',
          'field' => 'field_content_category_target_id',
          'id' => 'priority_widget_category',
      ),

  ];
}
```

What is causing this ajax error? Or is there an easy way to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The significant line from that error is: `The value  is not an array for in on filter: : Category`

If you grep in core for "is not an array for" you'll get `modules/views/src/Plugin/views/filter/InOperator.php`, specifically a line in its validate function that is testing `$this->value` to see if it's an array.

```
$errors[] = $this->t('The value @value is not an array for @operator on filter: @filter', array('@value' => var_export($this->value), '@operator' => $this->operator, '@filter' => $this->adminLabel(TRUE)));
```

Try to debug and find out if there's anywhere in your custom views filter that $this->value is equal to a string or something, and convert it to an array.